# Angular parse error - Can't bind to ... since it isn't a known property of

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Good day! It's my first projects on Angular (& Ionic) and I tried to build it following example from the book. There is no downloadable source code provided, so I can't compare to original and trace an error.

While I run my code I see that error in the console log.

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to **'events'** since it isn't a known property of **'event'**. 
    ("
    
    
      ][events]="events">
    "): ng:///AppModule/EventListPage.html@6:24
    'event' is not a known element:

I checked my components and page template twice, but still struggle to spot my mistake. Would be really appreciated if you point to an error. Full code of the project is uploaded on the gitHub https://github.com/eaailkal/baahandbook/tree/master/src

[Here is the image with example, which I was following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/376N0.png)

Thank you in advance :)

Here is page **event-list.html** template code

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Events</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <event *ngIf="events" [events]="events"></event>
</ion-content>
```

**event-list.ts** code

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { Events } from '../../model/Events';
import { EventsService } from '../../providers/events-provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'event-list',
  templateUrl: 'event-list.html'
})
export class EventListPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  events: Events;
  subscription: Subscription;
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private eventService: EventsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.eventService.load(0, 10).subscribe(events =>
this.events = events);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
} }
```

Here is **events-provider.ts** code

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as isEqual from 'lodash.isequal';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
// import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Events } from '../model/Events';

@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }
  load(offset: number = 0, limit: number = 10): Observable<Events> {
    return this.db.list('/events')
      .map(ids => ids.slice(offset, offset + limit).map(v => v.$value))
      .distinctUntilChanged(isEqual)
      .map((ids: any[]) => ids.map(id => this.db.object('/'
+ id)))
      .map(events => ({
        offset,
        limit,
        total: limit,
        results: events,
})); }
}
```

My 2 components are provided below

**event.ts**  and **event.html**  component

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Event } from '../../model/Event';

// import AngularFire and FirebaseListObservable modules 
// from the AngularFire 2 library to provide bindings to Firebase
// import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'event',
  templateUrl: 'event.html'
})
export class EventComponent {
  @Input() event: Event;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="!event">
  Loading...
</div>

<div *ngIf="event">
  <h2 class="title">{{ event.title }}</h2>
  <div>
    <span>
      <ion-icon name="time"></ion-icon>{{ event.date }} - {{ event.time }}
    </span>
    <span>
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      {{ event.location }}
    </span>
    <span>
      <ion-icon name="bulb"></ion-icon>
      {{ event.description }}
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>
      <ion-icon name="link"></ion-icon>
      {{ event.url }}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**events.ts** and **events.html** component

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from '../../model/Events';


@Component({
  selector: 'events',
  templateUrl: 'events.html'
})

export class EventsComponent {
  @Input() events: Events;
}
```

```html
<ion-list *ngIf="events.results.length > 0">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let event of events.results">
    <event [event]="event | async"></event>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<p *ngIf="events.results.length === 0">
  No events.
</p>
```

**event.ts** model

```js
export interface Event {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  time: number;
  date: number;
  description: string;
  location: string;
  url: string;
}
```

**events.ts** model

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Event } from './Event';

export interface Events {
  offset: number;
  limit: number;
  total?: number;
  results: Observable<Event>[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed one *s*  in your `@Input`

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Event } from '../../model/Event';

// import AngularFire and FirebaseListObservable modules 
// from the AngularFire 2 library to provide bindings to Firebase
// import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'event',
  templateUrl: 'event.html'
})
export class EventComponent {
  @Input() events: Event; <-----change here
}
```

or remove one *s*  from your `event-list.html` like

```
<event *ngIf="events" [event]="events"></event>
```

Comment: Hi Sainu! Thank you for your reply and your time. I've tried both, but however it did not work for me. 
[Here is the image with example, which I was following][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/376N0.png

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem. 
Just went through **app.module.ts** and found out that both my components were not imported.